# Segmentation fault in a C++ program finding occurrence of a character in repeated string

Tags: c++, string, exception

Following code counts total occurrence of a character,'a' in string,s repeated upto n number of characters :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

long repeatedString(string s, long n) 
{
    long count=0,i;
    char *s1{ new char[n]{} };
    int j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s1[i]=s[j++];
        if(j==s.size())
            j=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s1[i]=='a')
            count++;
    }
    return count;

}

int main()
{
   string s = "abaca";
   long n = 12;
   cout<<repeatedString(s,n);
   return 0;
}
```

It runs fine with following input:

Eg. Here `s` is "`abaca`" , `s1` will be "`abacaabacaab`" so `n` gets calculated to 7.

But if `s` is "`a`" and `n` is `1000000000000` , it gets aborted due to bad_alloc

Can anyone help me solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `s1[i]` exhibits undefined behavior for any value of `i`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds, since `s1` is an empty string.

Comment: In any case, you don't want to literally build a string `1000000000000` characters long - that's 1 terabyte of data, your computer doesn't have that much RAM. The problem can be solved without generating a huge string.

Comment: To count the number of times a char occurs in a string use `auto n = std::count(s1.begin(), s1.end(), 'a');`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

We start with`s1.size() == 0` and for a string `s1[i]` is invalid for any value of `i` greater or equal to `s1.size()`. In this case it is always invalid.

Change `s1[i]=s[j++];` to `s1 +=s [j++];`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I modified string s1="" to char *s1{ new char[n]{} }; Still the problem persists

Comment: @YogitaNegi I would advice you to remove code and re-add it to chase the issue down. Also, using `std::cout` will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The object s1 of the type std::string is empty

```
string s1="";
```

So you may not use the subscript operator to change it

```
    s1[i]=s[j++];
```

You could declare the object like

```
string s1( n, ' ' );
```

In this case it contains n elements that can be changed using the subscript operator.

Another approach is to use the operator +=. For example

```
string s1;
s1.reserve( n );

//...
```

s1 += s[j++];

Pay attention to that the value 1000000000000 of the parameter n can be too big and the system will be unable to allocate such a string.

In this case you have  to check whether the system is able to allocate enough elements for the object.

For example

```
string s1;

if ( not ( n < s1.max_size() ) ) n = s1.max_size();
s1.reserve( n );
```

and then

s1 += s[j++];

Pay attention to that the return type of the function should be at least `size_t` but it will be even better to use `std::string::size_type`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type repeatedString( const std::string &s, std::string::size_type n ) 
{
    std::string s1;

    if ( not( n < s1.max_size() ) ) n = s1.max_size();

    s1.reserve( n );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        s1 += s[j++];

        if ( j == s.size() ) j = 0;
    }

    std::string::size_type count = 0;

    for ( const auto &c : s1 )
    {
        if ( c == 'a' ) ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "abaca" );

    std::string::size_type n = 12;

    std::cout << repeatedString( s, n ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
7
```

Instead of the range-based for loop in the function

```
    for ( const auto &c : s1 )
    {
        if ( c == 'a' ) ++count;
    }
```

you could use the standard algorithm `std::count` declared in the header `<algorithm>`.

If the system is unable to allocate a string of a given size then it throws an exception of the type `std::bad_alloc`. You can catch the exception.

In this case the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type repeatedString( const std::string &s, 
                                       std::string::size_type n ) throw( std::bad_alloc ) 
{
    std::string s1;

    if ( not( n < s1.max_size() - 1 ) ) n = s1.max_size() - 1;

    s1.reserve( n );

    return n;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        s1 += s[j++];

        if ( j == s.size() ) j = 0;
    }

    std::string::size_type count = 0;

    for ( const auto &c : s1 )
    {
        if ( c == 'a' ) ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "a" );

    std::string::size_type n = 1000000000000;

    try
    {
        std::cout << repeatedString( s, n ) << '\n';
    }
    catch ( const std::bad_alloc & )
    {
        std::cout << n << " is too big value.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1000000000000 is too big value.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code also throws bad_alloc.How can I get desired output?

Comment: @YogitaNegi It seems that the system is unable to allocate a string of such a size. So catching the exception you can warn the user that the supplied value is too big.